# htaccess rewriting url with periods

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following

> domain.com/products/consumables/jetty 0.18mm

the

> jetty 0.18mm

gets picked up by PHP and taken into mysql to pull the product data and display it all onto the page.

Only problem is, the . in 0.18 kills the search as the url thinks its an extension.

How can I rewrite using htaccess to pick up any . in the last part of my url and then rewrite it so that it can work?

Im clueless with htaccess and help would be greatly appreciated.

**Current HTACCESS**

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteRule ^([^/.]*)/([^/.]*)$ index.php?c=$1&p=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]*)$ index.php?c=$1 [L]
```

Comment: check this http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/3890963.htm?highlight=msg3890997

Comment: Hard to tell with that little information you give. But check your options with encoding the 'product name' by some strategy to 'protect it'.

Comment: have added my current htaccess code to show how I get the domain to work as it is. I just need to get the period/dot to work now

Answer (score 0):

Replace your 2 RewriteRule lines with this line:

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)(\..*)?$ index.php?c=$1&p=$2 [L,QSA,NE]
```

And inside your `index.php` PHP code concatenate 2 GET params into one like this:

```
$pname = $_GET["c"];

if (!empty($_GET["p"])
   $pname .= '.' . $_GET["p"];
```

Comment: Looking at what you have put it combines the c and p into one instead of seperating it with a slash?

Comment: Sorry missed dot `.` while concatenation. Check now.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]*)/(.+)$ index.php?c=$1&p=$2 [L]
```

I used the following which has worked